# Circular Image View in Android without using any external library

Tags: android, imageview

Is there any way to make a circular image view in Android without using any external libraries? Something in android design libraries? And I should be able to set the image at run time using code.

Comment: sure:  `RoundedBitmapDrawable` -
 android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can put your ImageView inside CardView and set its corner radius.
Simple example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Note that the corner radius should be twice shorter than image size.

Comment: i got an error on card_view:cardCornerRadius="25dp"

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE**

Now we can create circular imageView for Android without using any third-party library or custom ImageView

Use **`ShapeableImageView`**

Check out this to know how to use [**`ShapeableImageView`**](https://github.com/askNilesh/circular-Imageview)

> OLD ANSWER

you can try this it is working fine in my device

create one `RoundedImageView` class like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView
{

    public RoundedImageView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctx, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius)
    {
        Bitmap finalBitmap;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
            finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                    false);
        else
            finalBitmap = bitmap;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
                finalBitmap.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f,
                finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```

now in your **layout.xm**l  use below code

```
<com.example.RoundedImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/disha" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks thats a great way . i was looking something for this ... this gives me a way to understand how to make custom views

Comment: This is a good solution. It even speeded up my app because I was storing a resized copy of source image inside the view. Now with this approach everything is lightning fast.. I avoided creating copies inside onDraw and used clip to clip out rounded shape and then filled it with the source image with the drawBitmap method that takes in Rectf-s

Answer (score 9):

To have a circular ImageView with new **Material components of Android** use **`ShapeableImageView`** of package **`com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView`**.

Property to apply is **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`**

Example:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivUserPic"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_75sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_75sdp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/labelTitle"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearance.Image.PILL" />
```

style:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearance.Image.PILL" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.Image.Top.PILL" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">6dp</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopLeft">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">6dp</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">rounded</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, best answer for current time. And I want to add that here you can find visualisation for ShapeableImageView:
https://howtodoandroid.com/shapeableimageview-material-components-android/

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do it if you use Material Design in your app

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/black">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/paymentlogo"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/your_img" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Working ,Thanks!! simple and perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sign_up_1"
            android:id="@+id/icon_val"
            />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

if you use androidx then
look at my code,it works fine

Comment: the solution at the top which needs v7 library doesn't work for androidx

Answer (score 0):

Jetpack Compose is Android’s modern toolkit for building native UI. It simplifies and accelerates UI development on Android.

To have a circular ImageView with Jetpack Compose in Android:-

```
    Image(
            painter = rememberImagePainter("https://...."),  //image URL
            contentDescription = "avatar",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(64.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
        )
```

For more Jetpack Compose sample codes,refer [this](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2021/08/03/jetpack-compose-1-0-0-sample-codes/)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CircularImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public CircularImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int h = getHeight();

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;

        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
            float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            float factor = smallest / radius;
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,
                    (int) (bmp.getWidth() / factor),
                    (int) (bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
        } else {
            sbmp = bmp;
        }

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final String color = "#BAB399";
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.7f,
                radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```

Try it..

Answer (score -1):

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

       public RoundedImageView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
              super(ctx, attrs);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

              Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

              if (drawable == null) {
                     return;
              }

              if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
                     return;
              }
              Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
              Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

              int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

              Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
              canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

       }

       public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
              Bitmap finalBitmap;
              if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
                     finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                                  false);
              else
                     finalBitmap = bitmap;
              Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                           finalBitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
              Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

              final Paint paint = new Paint();
              final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                           finalBitmap.getHeight());

              paint.setAntiAlias(true);
              paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
              paint.setDither(true);
              canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
              paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
              canvas.drawCircle(finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
                           finalBitmap.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f,
                           finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
              paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
              canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

              return output;
       }

}
```

You can make class of RoundImageView like this